# How to get class in the field value using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

Consider the following code

```
class Foo {

}

class Bar {
    private Foo foo = new Foo();
}
```

Is it possible in `Foo` class to get the class of `foo` field. I mean, I want in `Foo` to get `Bar` class. The question is of course about reflection, but not about `new Foo(Bar.class)`.

Comment: What do you mean? `Field foo = Bar.class.getDeclaredField("foo"); foo.setAccessible(true); foo.get(new Bar());`?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn No, I mean about the code in `Foo` class which has no information about `Bar`.

Comment: You mean the caller class? `StackWalker.getInstance(Set.of(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE).getCallerClass()`

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yes, thank you very much. However, I used your solution without any `Set` - `StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE)`. If you make and answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the callers Class, you can use the newish (introduced in Java 9) [`StackWalker`](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackWalker.html)  API:

```
class Foo {
    private static final StackWalker SW = StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE);

    public Foo() {
        Class<?> bar = SW.getCallerClass();
    }
}

class Bar {
    private Foo foo = new Foo();
}
```

If you use an older Java version, there is the unsupported  `sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass()`.

Comment: Is it safe to do `private static final StackWalker SW`? I mean when multiple threads will create instances of `Foo` at the same time and one `StackWalker` instance will be used?

Comment: It's only created once (it's static). And it's the best practice, as the getInstance might be costly.

Comment: I understand it is created only once, but is it safe? How will behave this single `SW` when there are several threads and several Stacks?

Comment: See the last paragraph in the [StackWalker Javadoc](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackWalker.html): `StackWalker` is thread-safe. Multiple threads can share a single `StackWalker` object to traverse its own stack. A permission check is performed when a `StackWalker` is created, according to the options it requests. No further permission check is done at stack walking time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.

Comment: But there is no guaranty that the caller of the `Foo` constructor is a member of the class containing a field of type `Foo`. Say, `class Bar { private Foo foo; Bar(Foo f) { foo = f; } } class Other { public static void main(String[] a) { Bar b = new Bar(new Foo()); } }`